# Java redeclaring class within itself

Tags: java

I realise that this might be a stupid question, but I have not come across this before. The extract below is declaring a class. But I do not know why or understand why the class is redeclared within it's self.

I am still learning the ins and outs of Java so would appreciate any help. Also I know I will have probably used incorrect terms as I am unversed in the details of Java. Please correct my ignorance.

```
public class TouchExampleView extends View {
    private Drawable mIcon;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    public TouchExampleView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are not redeclarations - these are constructors definitions. Each of those three definitions specify a way in which a `TouchExampleView` instance can be created. For example, in such expression:

```
TouchExampleView view = new TouchExampleView(context, someAttrs, style);
```

where types of arguments match types declared in the constructor definition (`Context`, `AttributeSet` and `int`) the third constructor will be called.

If you'd write

```
TouchExampleView view = new TouchExampleView(context, someAttrs);
```

the second constructor will be called. The `this` call in its body will make it run the third constructor with `defStyle = 0`.

Another thing worth being noted is a `super` call in the third constructor. It is a call to a super class constructor, which in this case is `View`.

Comment: Overloaded constructors, to be precise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not completely understanding why the extract I posted is built the way it is, but I can now at least research what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 constructors listed, known as constructor overloading (a subset of method overloading).  Each one is valid, but the last is the "master" constructor, which the first 2 constructors are chaining to, and providing default values for the omitted arguments.

The code that creates instances here can then choose which constructor it uses for creating a new instance of this class.